# Set date picker to a given date

Tags: php, mysql, html, date

Is there a way to set a datepicker to a given date?

I have tried this:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo date('yyyy-mm-dd', escape($user->data()->dob)); ?>"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

I just want to know if it is possible, but it can't just be set to 'now'. The only help I can see online is string manipulation, but not actually setting the datepicker.

Comment: do you want to print just today's date ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the date by using the datepicker function:

```
$("input[type=date]").datepicker(
    "setDate", "<?php echo date('Y-m-d')"
);
```

You need to check the format also of date in datepicker.

Or You can do this:

```
<input type="date" name="dob" 
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(escape($user->data()->dob))); ?>"/>
```

You need to add the strtotime function also.

Comment: Thank you so much! the PHP code worked!

Comment: A quick comment that might help others. Above code would not work for me but it guided me to the right direction. So i used the above code with the default format of the datepicker m/d/Y and removed the escape function so that makes it echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)); and that worked

Answer (score 2):

With jQquey Datepicker

```
$(function () {
    $("#dateSelector").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
$("#dateSelector").datepicker("setDate", "10/12/2012");
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smartnisarg23/49jGj/)

Answer (score 1):

try this for today date:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

change your format string:

```
value="<?php echo date('YYYY-mm-dd', escape($user->data()->dob)); ?>"
```

also make sure `escape($user->data()->dob));` is returning date string.

Answer (score 0):

```
value="<?php print date('d/m/Y'); ?>"
```

It will print only today's date.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in this format

use 'Y-m-d' format

```
 <input type="date" name="bday" value="2011-12-06">
```

**PHP CODE**

```
 <input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
 <input type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', escape($user->data()->dob)); ?>"/>
```